# Uninstalling Android ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

This seems like a trivial task, but I can't find an option to cleanly de-install the ADT from my Eclipse installation.
Of course, I could just delete the folder of the SDK, but this just throws errors when starting up Eclipse the next time. The reason I'm asking is because my old ADT keeps throwing a wierd error (Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml, reason: File not found) and I need a complete, fresh re-install.

**Important:**
under
Help -> about eclipse sdk -> installation details 
the uninstall button for all android plugins is greyed out

Comment: it also applies to ubuntu 12.04 LTS, thanks

Answer (score 216, accepted):

The only way to remove the ADT plugin from  Eclipse is to go to `Help > About Eclipse/About ADT > Installation Details`.

Select a plug-in you want to uninstall, then click `Uninstall...` button at the bottom.

[image]

If you cannot remove ADT from this location, then your best option is probably to start fresh with a clean Eclipse install.

Comment: this doesnt uninstall the plugin, it just removes the link to the repository

Comment: thnx, but strangely enough, the uninstall button is greyed out when im selecting those plugins. I've resorted to uninstalling eclipse now.

Comment: Careful, on Mac OSX Mavericks this also mucked up Java alltogether which of course you kinda need to run Eclipse...

Comment: After I followed these steps I don't see the plug-in anymore so I think it worked for me.  Additionally, the green Android icon on the about page is gone as well.

Comment: On the Mac its under the Eclipse menu item. On my Mac with Eclipse Indigo, I had to delete all other Android stuff, like DDMS , traceview, etc. form the installed software list, and then also remove all the links form Available Software Site section under the Install window. Only after that it installed ADT 2.3.

Comment: @ShimonDoodkin I had the same problem, but I found it was something I forgot to do the uninstall "ADT" or other non restarted the "Eclipese", even if he asks. First uninstall the software as suggested in this response, the eclipse will ask to reboot, then you cancel, then go to 'help > Install New Software (or Check for Updates)".

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution by myself after doing some research:

- Go to Eclipse home folder.
- Search for 'android' => In Windows 7 you can use search bar.
- Delete all the file related to android, which is shown in the results.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Install the ADT plugin again and Restart plugin.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: I tried your approach. Even though everything is deleted eclipse still claims to have an old dependency, not allowing me to update to the latest ADT version (23). thumbs up for eclipse!

Answer (score 6):

I had the issue where after updating the SDK it would only update to version 20 and kept telling me that ANDROID 4.1 (API16) was available and only part of ANDROID 4.2 (API17) was available and there was no update to version 21.

After restarting several times and digging I found (was not obvious to me) going to the SDK Manager and going to FILE -> RELOAD solved the problem.  Immediately the other uninstalled parts of API17 were there and I was able to update the SDK.  Once updated to 4.2 then I could re-update to version 21 and voila.

Good luck!
David

Comment: Wow, i work from several machines and have had this issue more than once. Each time it took me a lot of monkey business to get it fixed. Your info worked and was by far the fastest solution, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If running on windows vista or later,
remember to run eclipse under a user with proper file permissions.
try to use the 'Run as Administrator' option.

Comment: thnx, however I was running it on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem after clicking update plugins, 
i tried all the suggestions above and failed , the only thing that worked for my is reinstalling android studio..