# ADT 21 update not recognized by Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I just updated my ADT plugin for Ecipse to v21 but after a restart it is not working.

Somehow the plugin's are version 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525, but the SDK verification is telling me that I am on v20.2.v201207191942-407447 and forcing me to update.

I've tried removing the plugin but that's not possible trough the help > about > Installation details. Reverting back to older installations let me reinstall the update but with the same result.

Im using Eclipse Juno 20120614-1722

can anyone point me in the direction to fix this?

---

**UPDATE:**

As it turned out, Windows 7 UAC was at play here. I thought i was running eclipse as admin, but i wasn't. What the strange part is, is that Eclipse tried to install the updates but fails without ever mentioning that it does not have the right to changes files without administrative rights. the next time you boot up, the installation thinks its updated but the files are not.

**Solution:**

- Run in Administrator mode (by setting it as standard in your shortcut
  or turn UAC off)
- Roll back to a previous installation (Help > About
  Eclipse > Installation Details > Installation History > (select
  previous installation) Revert )
- Reboot Eclipse (be sure to have Administrator rights)
- Update without a problem :)

Comment: Did you update the SDK Tools to Rev 21 as well?

Comment: Yes, everything trough the SDK manager is updated as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest then. I updated my Indigo version this morning OK. I normally do the SDK/Tools first, quit Eclipse and restart it again from the command line with "eclipse -clean". When it comes up again, I go to the "Check for updates" menu and install just the plugin from there.

Comment: My colleagues didn't have any problems either, its just my installation that somehow fails. its strange because i get no errors on the installation what so ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out, Windows 7 UAC was at play here. I thought i was running eclipse as admin, but i wasn't. What the strange part is, is that Eclipse tried to install the updates but fails without ever mentioning that it does not have the right to changes files without administrative rights. the next time you boot up, the installation thinks its updated but the files are not.

**Solution:**

- Run in Administrator mode (by setting it as standard in your shortcut or turn UAC off)
- Roll back to a previous installation (Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installation History > (select previous installation) Revert )
- Reboot Eclipse (be sure to have Administrator rights)
- Update without a problem :)

Answer (score 11):

you have to update the eclipse so that it support the latest ADT.
To do this you have to select Help->Install New Software and then work with this link
update site: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.
After that update Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1):

As Kevin Grant said. I update the component one by one, and it works for me.

My eclipse is **Juno** Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800  installed with Fedora 17.

I notice that I can't see the adt in "Installed Software" tab in "Installation Details". I have to believe it's juno's fault. Because I already upgrade adt for eclipse in other workstation running eclipse indigo.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I did quite a few things as you suggested, deleted folders from plugins / metadata / features, none seemed to work. I googled how to uninstall ADT, and in the same place you uninstall it, theres a button to update it.

[Uninstalling Android ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt)

Just select anything that isn't tools 21 and update it individually. Worked for me (I started with updating ADT)

Answer (score 0):

The following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13460374/922756) worked for me on several machines that had this issue and does not require uninstalling or any other monkey business.

"go to the SDK Manager and going to FILE -> RELOAD solved the problem"

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem after update on SDK Manager v21.0 to v21.1. I had tried the suggested solution but didn't work for me. But I found a quick solution from developer.android website itself, I followed the "Troubleshooting Installation" part which you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

for a quick preview of solution:
1. Download the ADT Plugin zip file (do not unpack it).
2. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
3. Click Add, in the top-right corner.
4. In the Add Repository dialog, click Archive.
5. Select the downloaded ADT-21.1.0.zip file and click OK.
6. Enter "ADT Plugin" for the name and click OK.
7. In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next. (I add, also check the NDK)
8. In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
9. Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.

If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.

1. When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.