# Eclipse ADT plugins are not able to update to 21.0 version

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I have updated the Android SDK tools to 21 version in Android SDK. But when I open my eclipse it says to update the ADT tools in eclipse as SDK version is 21.0.

So I also tried to update the eclipse plugin but it is not updating and so I can not write code now. So What should I do to update ADT tools for eclipse?

I appreciate you answer if you have.

Comment: try uninstall the plugin and do clean install

Comment: How did you 'try to update', what does 'not updating' mean

Comment: means it is going for updating the ADT tools but progress is not made and automatically canceled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the automatic update fails for remote update site, you can try to install the latest ADT through the zip file. More information is available at [Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) > Troubleshooting Installation

Comment: I have tried it and zip file taking the data but eclipse is not updating the tools...do not why...:(

Comment: It gives following error:



Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7.
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo.
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo.
Unable to connect to repository https://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/content.xml
Connection timed out: connect
No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/indigo.**

Comment: You need to uninstall existing ADT plugin and install the new ADT version available in your zip file. The steps for installing the ADT through zip file is available in the link in my answer. The steps for uninstalling ADT is available in http://stackoverflow.com/a/9097282/1321873

Comment: Hi Rajesh,
I have try to install from zip but it connects to again update sites and giving then error.

Comment: It may be beneficial to find out why you are getting "No repository found" errors. I do not have any other suggestions for now.

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting  download latest version of ADT, current ADT-22.6.2.zip (*)
At Eclipse > Help > Install new software... > Uncheck Contact all update sites during install to find required software (bottom, last preference) in order to avoid any unwanted delays during install.
Same screen (top) Click Add > Archive > select downloaded ADT-X.X.X.zip > follow on screen installation steps

Answer (score 0):

> If automatic update fails,Try following..
>
> First download ADT plugin zip file from
> http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html.
>
> Then remove already installed
> all ADT plugins(DDMS,Hierarchy,NatveDevelopment,Traceview,TraceforopenGLES)
> from eclipse to avoid conflicts
>
> Help->about Eclipse->installation Details->installed softwares
>
> Uninsatll all ADT plugins and restart eclipse

---

> From Help->Install New software->ADD Select archive of ADT
> plugin zip

Install and restart your Eclipse

> If you have problems during installation relaunch eclipse with Run As
> Administrator mode.