# ADT won't update to 21.1

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have downloaded ADT in January. I just updated the SDK to latest. When I launch Eclipse, it get a warning that my SDK version now requires ADT 21.1, so I click to check for updates, but Eclipse does not find any udate.

Now most of my features no longer work, and prompt for a NullPointerException whenever I do any action.

Is there a way to force eclipse to update or to download the correct package and force the update?

Comment: The Android tag isn't really helpful here. Is that the ADT for CP/M, BS2000 or IBM/370?

Comment: isn't eclipse cross platform?

Comment: Java is supposed to be cross platform, the ADT downloads are different for Windows, Linux, Mac and each for 32 or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you tried making sure the Android SDK first? Goto Window > Android SDK Manager. Make sure all that is updated then try Help > Check For Updates again
- you could then try uninstalling the ADT plugin and -reinstall. ([Uninstalling Android ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt)) Google mentions if you have problems to uninstall it (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)
- if that doesn't uninstall correctly then you may have to have uninstalling and re-installing Eclipse entirely

Answer (score 1):

Also verify that your version of Java is patched to the latest update.  It's not a bad idea to reboot the computer after each update, too.