# ADT Plugin Disabled - > Installation Details Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I'm Trying to remove ADT from Eclipse 3.6. When i go to Installation Details ADT Plugin is disabled, hence i'm unable to install. I tried to remove plugin manually by referring this site

[http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in?)

After doing all that i'm able to see disabled ADT plugin like this...[image]

Please help me to come out of this problem...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What's the purpose of removing the ADT? You want to have a clean installation of Eclipse or something?

Comment: I'm Stopping android development so...

Answer (score 1):

Then this answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt) might help you. As I would have suggested, your best option is probably to start fresh with a clean Eclipse install:

The only way to remove the ADT plugin from  Eclipse is to go to `Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details`.

Select a plug-in you want to uninstall, then click `Uninstall...` button at the bottom.

[image]

If you cannot remove ADT from this location, then your best option is probably to start fresh with a clean Eclipse install.