# Can't update ADT plugin in Eclipse to version 23.0.0 or above

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I am beginner in Android programming.  My problem is, that I can not update ADT. The problem started, when after a long time I have updated in Android SDK Manager the Android SDK Tools. Then I was trying to import a project into the workspace. But I couldn't import that, because every time I clicked the Finish button, nothing happened. Then I closed Eclipse and opened it again, and showed me the following error:

[image]

I clicked on the Check for Updates, but it didn't find anything. On the Internet I have found an [URL](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/), so I clicked Help-->Install New Software...--> Add--> and pasted this URL. When I clicked Next, it showed me the list of items which I wanted to install and also an error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
 Software being installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
 Software currently installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 23.0.0.1245622)
Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Tracer for OpenGL ES 23.0.0.1245622 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.feature.group 23.0.0.1245622)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger [23.0.0.1245622]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger [21.0.0.v201210310015-519525]
```

I have also read somewhere, that I should try to replace the plugins folder with the updated plugins folder so I tried to rename "plugins" folder in the Eclipse folder to "pluginsx" and pasted the new one I have downloaded from the [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). After this I couldn't open the Eclipse.

This [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23) is also about the same problem as I have, and there is an answer which is accepted as the solution of the question. So I tried also to [download](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip), and copy those 3 things to folders which were mentioned in the comment below, but I have still the same problem, nothing changed.

So now I don't have any idea, how to fix this problem. Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Help-->Install New Software-->What is already installed?

Then, Select "Android DDMS, Andoid Devlopment Tools,Android Hierarcy Viewer, Android native Development Tools, Android Traceview, Tracer for OpenGL ES" and click Uninstall.

After all this step, try Add link (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and name is ADT Plugin. This link will get the latest ADT Plugin. In this way you reinstall the ADT.

Comment: I cant uninstall ADT because is tells me it needs to delete eclipse.exe

Comment: do not try to uninstall the Android Developer Tools option. Just uninstall the aforesaid plugins only

Comment: @SQLiteNoob  same with me...did you find any solution?

Comment: When I select these mentioned packages, the Uninstall button stays inactive. HELP!

Comment: Exquisite. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

None of these "update" alone answers worked for me.

The solution I used is to uninstall the ADT (from Uninstalling Android ADT)

```
Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details
```

Select all of the Android modules (prefixed with com.android.ide...)

and delete them (Uninstall...) and re-add the libraries from the

```
help > Install new software
```

As listed above....

Comment: I was hoping that this answer will help as none of the suggestions worked for me, but when i did it, it deleted parts of my eclipse installation (e.g. eclipse.exe is deleted) and now i have to download and reinstall the whole eclipse again.

Comment: Deleting the libs removed your eclipse.exe?  Doesn't seem likely.  I suspect you tried "a number of things" first -- like we all were -- and one of those steps whacked the installation...

Comment: My colleague said that this solved the problem. He also said **not to restart Eclipse after uninstalling the ADT**, and instead just directly install the new ADT as explained above.

Comment: I did what he said, and it works like magic. Do not restart your eclipse after uninstalling and MAKE SURE you REMOVE ALL the android libraries (all with com.android.. prefixed).

Comment: @Andrew T. I restarted eclipse after uninstalling the ADT. Wow.. What a mess!

Comment: what happens if you restart, because I just did.

Comment: Did you follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt ?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked to me was to download the current Eclipse ADT bundle from the Android [site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

After download it, I copied my current sdk to a folder like **.../development/sdk**. Then I deleted the sdk that came with this new Bundle.

I put ADT Bundle in **.../development/adt-bundle-...**.
After start it, you jave to inform the new sdk location in `Window > Preferences > Android`, so in SDK Location you put the new sdk path. In my case: **.../development/sdk**.

Of course, you can put the sdk folder inside the new ADT Bundle folder, but I do this way, because I use Android Studio as well, so I point the two IDEs to the same SDK.

After finish this and be sure everything is working I deleted the old ADT Bundle folder.

Answer (score 0):

Installing ADT is a major problem specially when updating. Also sometimes it's just a pain to install ADT by providing the direct link. Often Eclipse will stall while displaying "Calculating requirements and dependencies".

I found it simpler at times to first uninstall all the 7 components:

-Android DDMS
-Andoid Devlopment Tools
-Android Hierarcy Viewer
-Android Native Development Tools
-Android Traceview 
-Tracer for OpenGL ES
-Google App Engine Tools for Android(If installed)

Then download the [latest ZIP/Archive](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Install the Archive from Help->Install New Software->Add->Archive

 Select the downloaded ZIP, provide a name for it and follow the standard installation process.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following solution worked for me.

I had installed SDK Platform of M Preview while my ADT was of version 22.
So I just uninstalled SDK Platform of M preview and installed SDK platform of API level 22 from SDK Manager.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

this solution works.!!!!!!!

Open eclipse> Help>about eclipse>Installation

uninstall the component the are included to the .zip file you downloaded. download like below.

(credit to mr.zakimark

I found it simpler at times to first uninstall all the 7 components:

-Android DDMS
-Andoid Devlopment Tools
-Android Hierarcy Viewer
-Android Native Development Tools
-Android Traceview 
-Tracer for OpenGL ES
-Google App Engine Tools for Android(If installed)

Then download the [latest ZIP/Archive](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Install the Archive from Help->Install New Software->Add->Archive 
Select the downloaded ZIP, provide a name for it and follow the standard installation process.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't uninstall the old ADT plugins from the 'Help->Installation Details` page because the 'Uninstall...' button was disabled when I selected any of the modules.

Also, because the ADT bundle is no longer available to download, reinstalling was not an option.

What worked for me was to install the basic Eclipse environment using the Eclipse Installer from [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/). In the installer, I selected 'Advanced Mode...' from the hamburger menu, and then selected just the 'Eclipse Platform' to install, i.e. just the core tools. I think that this is only possible using the installer.

After eclipse was installed, I installed all the ADT plugins using 'Help->Install New Software' and using link https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.

YMMV, but this worked for me.