# Update ADT to latest version

Tags: android, eclipse

I know it is a **duplicated** question, but I couldn't find an accurate solution. Here is my problem:

[image]

but when: Help>Check for Updates, it says No updates were found.
any suggestions please??

Comment: My answer on same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491656/cant-update-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-to-version-23-0-0-or-above/24491819#24491819

Comment: @serifsadi, does not work for me.

Comment: The [serifsadi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491656/cant-update-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-to-version-23-0-0-or-above/24491819#24491819) comment was the answer to my question. [THE ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491656/cant-update-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-to-version-23-0-0-or-above/24491819#24491819)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

**Help --> Install new software**

Then choose "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" from the drop down list and update the ADT

IF THIS THROWS ERROR Like this

No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685

Modify **http: to https**:

Sample : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

And then update ADT. This method worked for me.

**EDIT**

Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software” while updating.

OR

remove the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ site and then re-add it

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to eclipse > help > Install new software
2. Click on Add
3. Add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
4. Give it any name.

It will list the updates available, which'll include the latest adt.

Answer (score 0):

Go to following: 
'Help'->'Install New Software' and

type https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select ADT option and install it. It will update the ADT.

Answer (score 0):

one of the other answers worked for me using the ADT bundle published on developer.android.com.

I ended up downloading the latest version of Eclipse (not the ADT bundle) and then installing the ADT plugin via Help > Install new software > entering https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

I also had to update my workspace to point to my previous workspace, and most things seemed to be restored.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But it practically solved itself by updating to the latest ADT Plugin via Help -> Check for Updates. After a few times refreshing the repositories the right ADT appeared and Eclipse said it will uninstall the old one and setup version 23.0 and yes, I used the Android SDK Manager to get the latest Android SDK Tools.

BTW, there is a new and revised Android SDK Tools available via the Android SDK Manager and a new ADT 23.0.1. available via Updates that everyone should get. It appears to correct some issues with support libraries people had.

Answer (score 0):

None of these "update" alone answers worked for me.

The solution I used is to uninstall the ADT (from [Uninstalling Android ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt))

```
Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details
```

Select all of the Android modules (prefixed with com.android.ide...) and delete them (Uninstall...)

and re-add the libraries from the

```
help > Install new software
```

As listed above....