# Can't update ADT in Eclipse to version 23

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I've just updated the Android SDK in Ubuntu to r23 and was prompted by Eclipse to update my ADT to version 23 as well. However, when I check for updates in Eclipse, it informs me that there are no updates.

I then tried to download the ADT23 zip archive and use Install Software in Eclipse to update it, but it then throws dependency errors as my previous versions are still installed.

How do I update my ADT?

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse 4.2.2

Comment: I also got this issue while updating ADT. Uninstall the existing dependencies and install the new ADT using URL or zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Help -> about eclipse -> installation details

Now you can see the plugin you installed , delete the previous plugin that you want to update and then install your ADT as describe [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) .
My problem solved by this way ...

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491656/cant-update-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-to-version-23-0-0-or-above?rq=1) maybe be useful !

Comment: Thanks, uninstalling and reinstalling works.

Comment: Doesnt work in Eclipse with bundled ADT. The Uninstall option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing.

**Goto:** Help --> Install new software.
Select your ADT url in "Work with" dropdown.
It will list the Developer tools.
Now select all and press next.

You should be able to update it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to currently use ADT v23 is to manually download Eclipse from http://eclipse.org and then install ADT. You can find the instructions to install ADT here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

remove your ADT and install new one if it does not work 
check that you have permission to the site to download the ADT
maybe your country filtered the linked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want ADT 23.0.0 then check all the dependencies -

> ***ADT 23.0.0 (June 2014)***
>
> Dependencies:
>
> - Java 7 or higher is required if you are targeting the L Developer    Preview.
> - Java 1.6 or higher is required if you are targeting other releases.
> - Eclipse Indigo (Version 3.7.2) or higher is required.
> - This version of ADT is designed for use with SDK Tools r23.0.0. If    you haven't already installed SDK Tools r23.0.0 into your SDK, use
>     the Android SDK Manager to do so.

Source: [Eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

**NOTE:**

Also check the following post - [update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23).

Comment: I have Java 1.6.0_21-b06 installed
I have Eclipse 4.2.2 installed
I already have SDK Tools r23.