# Getting error This Android SDK requires Android Developer Tool kit version 23.0.0 or above even when it is already installed

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Its been almost  a week now that I am stuck on this issue. I wanted to update my `Eclipse to Lollipop.` In order to achieve this I downloaded the required **SDK** and **ADT23.0.4** package. I **uninstalled ADT22.0** and **installed ADT23.0.4 package**.
 Now when I  run ***eclipse->Help->About*** `ADT` It still shows Build: `v22.3.0-887826` where as when I go to ***Installation Details->Installed*** Software it shows `ADT   Android Development Tools 23.0.4.1468518`. My problem is when I change the path of ***SDK to lollipop*** one it gives an ***error--***

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Tool kit version 23.0.0 or ab...s 22.3.0.v201310242005-887826
```

when `ADT23.0.4` is already installed ***why does it keep showing this error??*** Any response to push me in the right direction will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, was able to solve in this way -

1. Eclipse-->Help-->About Eclipse---->Installation Details
2. Select - Android DDMS, ADT, Android Hierarchy Viewer, Android Native
   Development Tools, Android TraceView and Tracer for OpenGL ES
   packages. All must be version 22.xx
3. Uninstall all the plugins selected above.
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Install ADT from update site - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

***And another way is to try this***

*Help --> Install new software*

Then choose "Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" from the drop down list and update the `ADT`

IF THIS THROWS ERROR Like this

No repository found containing: `osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685`

*Modify http: to https:*

Sample : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Hope it may help u

Comment: Thanks for replying however its not working either i have tried both the ways you have suggested..still facing the same problem..

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I completely uninstall ADT because when I uninstall from Help->About ADT->Installation Details->Installed Softwares. It does remove all the plugins from there however when I go to About ADT it still shows version as V22. I think am not able to remove it completly..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491656/cant-update-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-to-version-23-0-0-or-above go through this link