# I installed another android api, then I got error that adb needs to update, now eclipse not starting

Tags: android, eclipse

I was following solution at
[Can't update ADT plugin in Eclipse to version 23.0.0 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491656/cant-update-adt-plugin-in-eclipse-to-version-23-0-0-or-above) exactly what was said, because I was in the same shoes.

I removed the Android Developer Tools as well, as suggested in the answer, but now I can't even start eclipse getting error of

> The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion
>   shared library.

I searched this problem but their scenario was different from mine.
Please help, I've spent hours on this issue.

Comment: Whenever I got stuck like this I found it quickest to download the whole lot from scratch.

Comment: Maybe good time to switch to Android Studio if you've got some time to spend learning how to use it and gradle.

Comment: hahaha, thanks Weston. Switching to Android studio on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redownload `Android SDK Platformtools` in the `Android SDK Manager`

[image: Android SDK Manager]