# Error when creating a new Android test project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I'm using Version: Luna Release (4.4.0) Build id: 20140612-0600 with ADT Version: 23.0.2.1259578.

I am working on an Android project and whenever I try to create a new test project by right-click on my project in Package Explorer->Android Tools->New Test Project... I get an "Unhandled event loop exception" and nothing happens.

I tried to create an new test project using File->New->Other->Android Test Project and all I managed to get was an empty test project with nothing in it. I doubt the project created this way is ok.

I searched on Google for a solution to my problem but I can't find anything related to it.

I tried to drop the projects from eclipse and import them again, closing eclipse, deleting the workspace and creating again. Nothing seems to be working.

Below is the error log export from eclipse:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.225
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\connectivity\CardReader\CardReaderSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.310
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\media\MediaRouter\MediaRouterSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.360
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\ui\DisplayingBitmaps\DisplayingBitmapsSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.377
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\ui\SlidingTabsBasic\SlidingTabsBasicSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.384
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\ui\SwipeRefreshLayoutBasic\SwipeRefreshLayoutBasicSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.390
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\ui\SwipeRefreshListFragment\SwipeRefreshListFragmentSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 1 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.394
!MESSAGE NPW ignoring malformed manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\samples\android-20\ui\SwipeRefreshMultipleViews\SwipeRefreshMultipleViewsSample\tests\AndroidManifest.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-07-23 23:59:53.447
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.replace(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.descriptors.PkgDesc.patternReplaceImpl(PkgDesc.java:564)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.descriptors.PkgDesc.getListDescription(PkgDesc.java:543)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.local.LocalPkgInfo.getListDescription(LocalPkgInfo.java:244)
    at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.getExtraSamples(SdkManager.java:309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.SdkSelectionPage.loadSamplesForTarget(SdkSelectionPage.java:221)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.SdkSelectionPage.onSdkTargetModified(SdkSelectionPage.java:192)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.SdkSelectionPage.onSdkLoaded(SdkSelectionPage.java:471)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.newproject.SdkSelectionPage.createControl(SdkSelectionPage.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:759)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createContents(WizardDialog.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1101)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.actions.OpenWizardAction.run(OpenWizardAction.java:142)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.actions.NewTestProjectAction.run(NewTestProjectAction.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: nobody encountered this problem so far?

Comment: I had similar problem with wizards on Juno, SDK 4.4.2 and old SDK tools install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uninstall ADT and than re-install it.

this answer for uninstallation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097282/942224

and this [doc](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) for install ADT.

Comment: it didn't work. I tried it already. Initially I updated from Eclipse Indigo to Luna. After that I downloaded a clean archive of Luna release from Eclipse website and installed ADT on it. Same problem happens

Comment: I uninstalled Google SDK, ADT and installed them again and now I can create test projects. Thanks for the suggestion.