# changes to be made to use new adt bundle over the previous version

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using eclipse adt bundle. updated the sdk but not able to update ADT to version23
But its not updating.

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>     Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
>     Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720)
>       Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer 23.0.3.1327240)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: ADT Package 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.0.0
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Developer Tools 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 22.0.1.v201305230001--685705)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.feature.group [22.0.1.v201305230001--685705]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 23.0.3.1327240 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group 23.0.3.1327240)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [23.0.3.1327240]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Hierarchy Viewer 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group 22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720)
>       To: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer [22.6.1.v201403111859-1066720]

Now i downloaded new adt bundle. So now what changes do i have to make to start using it. Like -do i have to delete .android folder?
And can i use the keystores i used to sign my applications with the previous eclipse bundle?
Please advise.

Comment: uninstall adt from eclipse and install again do u understand

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar i am using eclipse that comes in the adt bundle. How can i uninstall adt from the eclipse

Comment: Have a Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar i tried it but not able to uninstall all this happened after i updated to ADT 23 from sdk manager

Comment: not big think i also do alotes of time

Comment: after this update the eclipse is not working. now i downloaded the new adt bundle so what should i do to start using it

Comment: i m asking to u frist uninstll adt and than install adt not update that take 30 minit to download latest adt

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar i tried to uninstall but its not uninstalling. thats why i downloaded new adt bundle. Now what i have to do to use it? I already tried this before i posted this question

Comment: may be u r doing something wrong

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar did you update your sdk to version 23? I di and this problem started. Now can you tell me what i have to do to use new bundle and what changes do i have to make?

Comment: yes alotes of meachine not single meachine

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar ok so was it successfully updated? Because i couldn't

Comment: Go to Help-AboutEclipse-installation detial and unintall not all only Adt LIke Android DDMS,Android Developer Tools.,Android Hierarchy Viewer.,Android Native Developer Tools.Android Traceview and OpenGL

Comment: @Naveen Tamrakar I tried this also even i tried to revert the installation from installation history but in vain