# Unable to generate R file with Eclipse and android version 5.0

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

Hi I am facing one different kind of problem. I have updated my android sdk manager with new android version 5.0(API level 21). After that I created new android application project but it giving error for resources. I have check in gen folder there is no R.Java file. And also as soon as I change my project properties to lower API level like 19 then it is working fine. I am using Kepler eclipse version. I am not sure bucause of what reason it is giving me this problem. Need some help. Thank you.

Comment: Uninstalling Android ADT  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt and  Reinstalling Android ADT may be slove your problrem

Comment: Did you remember to do Help/Check for Updates? Followed by an Eclipse restart?

Comment: Yeaah I update my eclipse after that.

Answer (score 0):

It was java version issue. I updated my java version from 1.6 to 1.7 and its working fine now