# Eclipse/ADT hangs when trying to launch

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Whenever I try to launch my Android app, Eclipse hangs.

This doesn't happen all the time, but has increased in frequency lately.

Sometimes it takes up to 10 minutes.

Any ideas?

[image: Build hangs while launching]

[image: Versions]

Comment: which net connection do u have like wifi and mobiledata

Comment: uninstall adt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt and reinstall ADT

Comment: Too many open apps and a slow CPU may be the culprits.

Comment: The labtop is on wired network. It hangs even before it asks about target platform to run on, so nothing related to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a bunch of rather large pngs were added to the project. 
This results in the build time increasing drastically due to png crunching, leading to the impression that it would be "hanging".
This only happens after a clean, or when switching branches, which happens a lot.

The fix is to get rid of the large pngs.