# Android ADT build path issue, how to fix?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[image] I installed android adt with eclipse and appcompat v7 is showing error I tried almost everything i.e
1.change the build path
2.re installing the whole package
3.include the jar files manually
4.Updating the eclipse

Please check for the error in picture.[image]

Please help me its two days I am struggling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt  uninstall and install adt

Comment: can you similarly show the screenshot of problems tab ?

Comment: added the problem tab screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone getting the same problem delete appcompat_v4 from the libs folder when creating a new project

Answer (score 1):

You have installed the higher version of jdk. just follow the below steps.

right click on project properties > click on java compiler, enable project specific settings and change the java version to 1.4 or lower.

Comment: by doing that a new error got raised "Description Resource Path Location Type
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.4' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties. appcompat_v7  line 1 Android ADT Problem
"

Comment: add appcompat_v7.jar to the bin folder of the appcompat_v7 in your workspace.

Comment: after making changes, restart the eclipse ide